# can't launch jupyter notebook on python image

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I m not able to launch new jupyter-notebook from my project.

Below my dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.9.0
ARG WORK_DIR=/opt/dir1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install cron -y && apt-get install -y default-jre
# Install python libraries
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
WORKDIR $WORK_DIR
EXPOSE 8888
VOLUME /home/data/dir1/
# Copy etl code
# copy code on container under your workdir "/opt/dir1"
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
CMD ["jupyter-notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root]
```

then in my terminal i did

```
#build
docker build -t my-python-app .
#run
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v /home/data/dir1/:/opt/dir1 my-python-app
```

but untill know there is no container running either no notebook open.

Does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your container in background mode. Also your image name is incorrect

```sh
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v /home/data/dir1/:/opt/dir1 -d my-python-app
```

Comment: thank you yacin, please what do you mean with background?

Comment: Add -d option to your docker run command.

Comment: yes but why? i tried by the way you solution but as usual when i did **docker ps** there is no running container and when i did docker ps -a i found terminated containers.

Comment: do you see what i mean.?